# Having multiple instances of video.js javascript video player

Tags: javascript

I am using videojs as the framework for a JavaScript video player page I am working on, its working great & I have customised the playback controls which are inside a div to match the spec I wanted (hide controls on load & then only show when the user has clicked play and has hovered etc).

I am now trying to make sure that the video player works when there is multiple instances on 1 page i.e if I add 4 or 5 videos to a page. the basic video.js functionality features seems to work fine but the additional control functionality which I have implemented will only work on the first instance of the video on the page (& thats because its just standard JS looking for that class & theres no unique ID per video player).

Here is what I have for the HTML:

```
<div class="cb-article-media__container padding-top-sm padding-bottom-sm">
      <div class="cb-article-media__video-block">
            <div class="c-video-container">
              <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin video-cover" width="100%" height="100%" controls preload="none"  poster="<?php echo esc_url($video_thumbnail_url); ?>"
      data-setup='{}'>
              <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
            </video>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="cb-article-media__container padding-top-sm padding-bottom-sm">
      <div class="cb-article-media__video-block">
            <div class="c-video-container">
              <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin video-cover" width="100%" height="100%" controls preload="none"  poster="<?php echo esc_url($video_thumbnail_url); ?>"
      data-setup='{}'>
              <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
            </video>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the JS:

```
  var videoContainer = document.querySelector('#videoPlayer');
  var videoControl = document.querySelector('.vjs-control');
  var timeDivider = document.querySelector('.vjs-time-divider');
  var timeDur = document.querySelector('.vjs-duration');

  var fullScrControl = document.querySelector('.vjs-fullscreen-control');

  $(document.body).on('click', '.vjs-fullscreen-control' , function(){
    if (videoContainer && videoContainer.classList.contains('vjs-fullscreen') ) {
      fullScrControl.className += " exit-full-screen";
    } else {
      fullScrControl.classList.remove("exit-full-screen");
    }
  });

  $(document.body).on('click', '.vjs-big-play-button' ,function(){
  // if (videoContainer.hasClass('vjs-playing')) {
    videoContainer.className += " show-controls";
  // }
});
```

How would I be able to make this JS/Jquery above work per instance of video player on the page (to show and hide the controls per player)? At present it only works for the first video player on the page.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is a codepen to the same issue:

https://codepen.io/nolimit966/pen/LYVyVzz

Thank you

Comment: Your IDs must be unique in the document: you are reusing the ID `videoPlayer` multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect - you have multiple elements with the same ID - `videoPlayer`. Each ID must be unique in its home subtree (document).

To fix this issue give each player a unique id, e.g.

```
 <video id="videoPlayer1" ...

 <video id="videoPlayer2" ...
```

In JS you just need make sure that you are controlling the correct player. To do this you probably just need to get the elements based on the control that was clicked rather than hard coding them.

You don't show the actual page markup - so this is a guess - but you want something like the following using "[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)".

```
  $(document.body).on('click', '.vjs-fullscreen-control' , function(){
      // note this is a guess, it could be $(this).parent, is the player you want. 
      var player = $(this).closest('.video-js')
      if(player.classList.contains('vjs-fullscreen')) {
         player.closest('.vjs-fullscreen-control').className += " exit-full-screen";
      } else {
         player.closest('.vjs-fullscreen-control').classList.remove("exit-full-screen");
      }
  });
```

In any case the principal remains the same - remove your hardcoded selectors and target the elements relative to the target of the click handler. If this doesn't work then please provide the full mark-up of a video player showing all the elements such as '.vjs-control' and '.vjs-fullscreen-control'